# ubuntu desktop official support on rpi4

Tags: 20.04, mate, raspberrypi, arm64

I have installed on rpi4 8Gb an ubuntu 20.04 server image for rpi4 64Bit
some setup and all work well.

After this I have installed ubuntu-desktop
some setup and all work with some little problem.

I ask if someone know if ubuntu-desktop will be official supported soon like ubuntu server?

I have to decide if stay using ubuntu-desktop or move to mate-desktop.

Have I to use ubuntu 20.04 server and `sudo apt install mate-desktop` or better use ubuntu-mate distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely. This has been discussed on several threads at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/

While it's possible to install Ubuntu Desktop on a Pi (you did), you probably also noticed that the Gnome Shell experience is, well, sluggish.

That's not a lack of support. That's a hardware limitation.

- Note that the present inability to boot from a LiveUSB is not a lack of support. That's a kernel bug (being fixed).

Comment: to me is not sluggish: is fast and I work wery well but with some little problem. Thank for your answer